# Can the mesh tear apart while grabbing(g)?

Tags: modeling

I don't know what is happening but the mesh tears apart when I try to stretch it. in the edit mode, I grabbed a point with proportional editing and snap to face enabled but the mesh got torn apart when I stretched it a little more.
file- [image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! At the moment, your question is a little unclear. Are you asking can it do that or are you asking how to fix it when it does that?

Comment: That could happen if your faces are not connected, try selecting your faces in edit mode, then press M and select Merge by distance

Comment: please show some screenshots or share your file

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter I am asking how to fix this?

Comment: That's what I was asking you.

Comment: @Emir it worked to some extent. thank you very much. please tell me why the faces got disconnected?

Comment: @YashGoyal I actually don't know, in order to find the issue, we need more info and images of your settings, objects,, etc... and alfo more information on how you made the model, there are a lot of possibilities on why the faces where disconnected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hey @Emir I have added the file and screenshot in the question. I hope this will clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

You probablt ripped it by accidentaly pressing V or you hid some vertex with H, try alt+H